# How to check API navigation pattern in VF page?(Summer 20 Update)

Tags: visualforce, api, summer20

Based on below link, I want to check existing VF page in my organization which use API navigation pattern.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_vf_navigation_calls.htm?edition=&impact=

How can I find out existing VF page? Looking for a syntax as I have never worked on VF page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the recent published knowledge article to see the consecutive api pattern - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000354894&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1